# Return JPA/Ebean query as a list of Integers

Tags: java, jpa, ebean

Currently my implementation is this:

```
ArrayList<Reports> listOfRep = new ArrayList<Reports>();
ArrayList<Integer> listOfId = new ArrayList<Integer>();

listOfRep.addAll(Ebean.find(Reports.class)
    .where()
    .eq("Name", "someName")
    .findList());

for (Reports r : listOfRep) {
    listOfId.add(r.id);
}
```

Right now I'm doing two loops to get a list of ID's (Integers). My Reports model has a field `int id`.I want to do something like

```
listOfId.addAll(Ebean.find(Reports.class)
    .select("id")
    .where()
    .eq("Name", "someName")
    .findList());
```

Where that query will return a list of Integer instead a list of Reports. Is there a way to refactor my original code into something simpler?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with a projection. Something like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
// for an Integer result :
CriteriaQuery<Integer> cq = cb.createQuery(Integer.class);
Root<Reports> reports = cq.from(Reports.class);
CompoundSelection<Integer> projection = cb.construct(Integer.class, reports.get("id"));

cq.where(cb.equal(reports.get("Name"), "someName")).select(projection);
List<Integer> resultList = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```